# Using this inside jQuery filter arrow function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

When having a code like this:

```
$elements.filter(() => {
    console.log(this); // will be the parent scope's "this"
});
```

you are not able to get the element that should be filtered.
So you would need to use a normal function, like:

```
$elements.filter(function(){
    console.log($(this)); // will be the element to filter
});
```

Is there any other way instead of using normal functions?
I know for click events you can use `event.currentTarget`, but there is no event parameter in `filter`.

Comment: TLDR: `(idx, node) => console.log( $(node) );` // replace 'this' with 'node'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While you don't get the reference to the expected `this`, it's possible to use the arguments supplied by the anonymous function, the index and the DOM node, in that order:

```
$elements.filter((index, node) => {
  console.log(node);
});
```

```js
let $elements = $('li');

$elements.filter((index, node) => {
  console.log(node);
});
```

```css
li {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
li.red {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li class="red"></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/vsjmwvo9/);

Comment: Ok, using `$(node)` in arrow functions and `$(this)` in normal functions seems to be equivalent

Comment: But I prefer naming the variable "element" instead of "node", as this is ambiguous towards real text nodes.

Comment: The names are entirely your choice; you can call them anything you want; so long as you remember that the first argument is the index of the current element amongst the collection, and the second argument is the DOM node itself (whether you call it "element," "node" or "tinkyWinky" it doesn't matter at all, so long as it's a valid variable name in JavaScript),

Comment: Sure, I just wanted to mention this for others. Naming it "node" in open source projects may be confusing.